# Conditional Expected Value Problem - Tree Diagram question

Tags: probability, statistics

> Some people believe that baseball players get hot.  One potential mathematical model is if a player had a hit in his last at-bat, then he will hit 0.300 in his next at-bat.  If he failed to hit, then he will hit 0.250 in his next at-bat.  Suppose that a player who has not been hitting well has three at-bats in a game.
>
> (a)  Find the expected number of hits the player gets in the game.
>
> (b)  Find the standard deviation for the number of hits this player gets in the game

I don't understand how you're supposed to know that for the first node, the Pr[Hit]=0.3 and Pr[Miss]=0.7.  In other words, for the first "at-bat", the player didn't have a previous hit so how do you know whether you should use 0.3/0.7 or 0.25/0.75 for the first node?

Once the tree is constructed then I know you just calculate the probability distribution and take the products of the random variable and probabilities to get the expected value...

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the diagram is wrong.  Not only has he not had a hit as of the first step... but the problem actually states that he "has not been hitting well", which I would think means you assume he didn't have a hit at his previous at bat.

Comment: @nrpeterson Yeah thanks thats what I thought.  This was in the solutions and didn't make sense to me.